# Efficient packet handling?

Tags: c#, networking, tcpclient

I've created a server in C# and am trying to efficiently handle data that comes in from clients. I currently have this code for checking for client packets on a client thread:

```
if ( myStream.DataAvailable == true && myStream.CanRead ) {
    int mySize = myStream.ReadByte();
    myBuffer = new byte[ mySize ];
    await myStream.ReadAsync( myBuffer, 0, mySize );
    ushort myPeek = 0;
    Net_Messages.Net_Read( myStream, myID, myBuffer, myPeek, myThreading );
}
```

So my question is, is it efficient to store the data from the stream into a buffer for each packet received from each client? Should I have a fixed predefined buffer instead of creating a new one for each packet retrieval?

How should I write data as well? Create a fixed pre-defined buffer for each client, store data on that buffer and send the buffer?

My problem with pre-defined buffers is allocating extra memory that is not needed by creating an unnecessarily sized buffer when I can create a new buffer for each packet at the correct size.

NOTE: Net_Read is a simple pass through function that passes the buffer and extra info as needed for processing the received packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly shouldn't usually allocate new buffer for each read, if that is what you mean. But beyond that, it depends a lot on context. For example, if incoming data is rare (web-sockets, for example), you might want to use a tiny buffer (even just a single byte) for the async read - and then use a larger buffer (perhaps from a pool) when data is available. Or you might want to use socket-polling instead! For busier connections it is not uncommon to end up using two buffers per connection - one fixed-size for reading, and one (perhaps a MemoryStream) as a back-buffer while you check for entire frames (which could come via multiple reads). Sometimes you can combine them (for example, SE.Redis uses the read buffer as the back-buffer, resizing it if needed, and copying data backwards in the buffer if we can consume some frames but have data left over).

There is no such thing as "efficient handling" - it depends entirely on context. What is efficient for one usage pattern could be highly inefficient for another. The number of concurrent connections and the frequency of reads are key factors.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for the info. :) Also, I don't believe I have access to socket polling with the TcpListener class.

Comment: @FatalSleep I wouldn't know: I only really use the Socket class. The abstractions add very little and take away a lot.

Comment: It's not as efficient as sockets and does lack some features, but it's easier to do. If you do happen to have a socket based tutorial rather than TcpClient though, I'm all ears.

Comment: @fatalsleep does "open socket, use socket, close socket" count as a tutrial? :)

Comment: Yes, it does count. :)

Comment: @FatalSleep more seriously, I actually do a lot of socket work; you could look at StackExchange.Redis on github, for example. But that is optimized for a particular scenario that might not be the same as yours. I also maintain the web-socket server that runs the live updates here on SO, but that is very very different socket usage (and isn't open source)

Comment: Web-sockets? I'd love to learn those as well! Alright, well I'll search around myself and see what I can do.

Comment: @FatalSleep the specification is actually quite fun to implement, if you like playing with bits

Comment: I don't mind messing with bits as long as the base socket system in the end functions better.